# Running a sub a cetain amount of times, each time with different data from a table?

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help again please? The code below works fine, thanks to UGP. I need to run this piece of code 215 times. Each time the numeric values in "Set sht = Sheet2" must be incremented by 1, and "rplcList = 2" must also be incremented by 1. All this to the point where both values are 216. How do I go about it? I must be quite simple, but for the life of me, I can not figure it out.

Do I create another Module in VB or what?

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
Set sht = Sheet2
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
fndList = 1
rplcList = 2

For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
      sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x),     Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _`
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to next another loop I think.

This should go through all worksheets from 2 - 216 and increment rplcList as well

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange

myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
fndList = 1
rplcList = 2
SheetNumber = 2

For SheetNumber = 2 To 216
    Set sht = Worksheets(SheetNumber)
    For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
       If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

       End If
    Next x
rplcList = rplcList + 1
SheetNumber = SheetNumber + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will go through each sheet in the workbook.

```
Public Sub Multi_FindReplace()

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Integer
    Dim rplcList As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
    fndList = 1
    rplcList = 2

    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
            For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
                Sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), _
                                  Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  MatchCase:=False, _
                                  SearchFormat:=False, _
                                  ReplaceFormat:=False
            Next x
            rplcList = rplcList + 1 'May want to move this outside the "End If" statement.
        End If
    Next Sht

End Sub
```

Documentation on `For....Each` loops:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you Darren. It works perfectly. Much appreciated.